# Python: Class attribute vs. List Index

Tags: python, list

I have a list of 'Purchase' objects currently stored in a list. I would like to get a subset of this list, do some complex analysis, and then update properties of the purchase objects, based on this analysis.

If I grab a subset of purchase records using a list comprehension, I get copies of the objects, I will get copies of these objects, so I must have a way of going back and updating the master list.

If I add an 'id' attribute to the purchase class. I can then look up the object in the master list by id, but I would like to be able to find it by index, which would be faster. I considered using a dictionary with the key being the identity, but somehow I feel I am missing the obvious solution.

To clarify the main issue here, it is that the list index of the subset cannot be used to find the original object in the master list that I want to update.

Comment: You know the saying how one picture worth a thousand words ? well same goes for a few lines of code ;)

Comment: Are you sure you would get copies of the objects? By default I would say you would get references to the originals. Please include your code :).

Comment: "If I grab a subset of purchase records using a list comprehension, I get copies of the objects"... nope. Python passes objects by reference.

Comment: Are you *mutating* the purchase objects, or are you creating new ones? Because if you did the former, you wouldn’t need to worry about updating any list since all reference still stayed the same.

Comment: Thanks all. Perhaps I have a bug.  Let me review my code see if I've missed something. If not I will post a code sample.

Comment: I ran a simple test, and the references are indeed the same, and therefore what I was trying to do is completely unnecessary.  I must have a bug in my code which I will sort out.  (and which I compounded by misreading some documentation) Thanks again.